# React-native: redirection for protected pages

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to manage the redirection for my routemap

I Have a StackScreen named 'root' contain url `/profile` and a stackScreen named 'notFound' contain the url `/not-found`.

My problem is for unconnected user, If I put the url `/profile`.   I have a redirection to `/sign-it` but If i put `/profiles` I have a redirection to /not-found

Can i put a not-found page for unconnected user if user would like to access a protected page.
I think is not good for security, the unconnected user can knows existing pages.

my code

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
function RootNavigator(e: any) {
  const { auth } = e
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={SignupScreen} />
      { auth && <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={DrawerNavigator} />}
      <Stack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

thanks

Comment: You might want to take a look at this post on security.stackexchangeby Conor Mancone, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/221277/how-good-are-angular-route-guards-from-a-security-standpoint/221281#221281, also cited in auth0's quick start guide to their React Client. It gets into protecting routes using react router, as well as returning redirects ,loadings, and not founds. Basically -- any client side restriction is, ultimately, for smooth UX. For security, protection comes by what routes connect on the server end.

Comment: Might also be worth taking a look at the auth0 guide to using protected routes written by Dan Arias, even if you're not using auth0 for your actual authentication. https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-react-user-authentication/#Protecting-Routes. The approach of using React Router and creating a "ProtectedRoute" wrapper component seems like it might give you some good insight/direction into the pattern you're trying to hit. I hope so anyway! It was really helpful for me on a similar problem.